# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'locust.events'

Tags: python, locust, rasa, modulenotfounderror

I'm a newbie of *python coding and I have faced a problem using [locust based code](https://github.com/salgieri/rasa-locust-stress-test) which is a stress testing tool for rasa socketio channel. I've proceeded as per the [README file](https://github.com/salgieri/rasa-locust-stress-test#readme) of stress testing tool and tried to fire up locust (pip installed locust) without doing any changes (only rasa_socket.py -> ws_url variable is configured).
When I try to run locust using this command,

```
locust --host=https://XXXXXXXXXXX.ngrok.io --locustfile rasa_socket.py --port=80
```

it pops up the following error in the cmd (I'm using a windows 10 OS, locust version 1.4.3). It says 'locust.events' not found.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "c:\program files\python\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\program files\python\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Tools\rasa socket load tester\load-test-venv\Scripts\locust.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "d:\tools\rasa socket load tester\load-test-venv\lib\site-packages\locust\main.py", line 125, in main
    docstring, user_classes, shape_class = load_locustfile(locustfile)
  File "d:\tools\rasa socket load tester\load-test-venv\lib\site-packages\locust\main.py", line 81, in load_locustfile
    imported = source.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 407, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 907, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 732, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Tools\rasa socket load tester\rasa-locust-stress-test\rasa_socket.py", line 2, in <module>
    from locust.events import request_success
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'locust.events'
```

rasa_socket.py file is as follows; What am I doing wrong here...?

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task, between
from locust.events import request_success
import socketio
import time
import random


class UserBehavior(TaskSet):
    statements = ['Can i buy toliet rolls', 'Can I come and visit the store', 'when can I visit the store',
                  'I need more medicine']

    def on_start(self):
        sio = socketio.Client()
        ws_url = "https://XXXXXXXXXXX.ngrok.io/socket.io/"
        sio.connect(ws_url, transports="polling")
        self.ws = sio
        self.user_id = sio.sid
        # body = json.dumps(["session_confirm", self.user_id])
        body = '{"session_request", {"session_id": "' + self.user_id + '"}}'
        self.ws.emit(body)

    def on_quit(self):
        self.ws.disconnect()

    @task(1)
    def say_hello(self):
        start_at = time.time()

        body = {"message": "Hello", "customData": {"language": "en"}, "session_id": self.user_id}

        # self.ws.send(body)
        self.ws.emit('user_uttered', data=body)

        request_success.fire(
            request_type='WebSocket Sent',
            name='test/ws/echo',
            response_time=int((time.time() - start_at) * 1000000),
            response_length=len(body),
        )

    @task(2)
    def say_random(self):
        start_at = time.time()

        statement = random.choice(self.statements)

        body = {"message": statement, "customData": {"language": "en"}, "session_id": self.user_id}

        # self.ws.send(body)
        self.ws.emit('user_uttered', data=body)

        request_success.fire(
            request_type='WebSocket Sent',
            name='test/ws/echo',
            response_time=int((time.time() - start_at) * 1000000),
            response_length=len(body),
        )


class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserBehavior
    wait_time = between(5, 15)

# 5c57023864bc4cf4bf82cf370d1b9349
# 0484184e70fa11eaad0ca45e60dc2e59
```

Comment: Double check your locust version by doing locust -V

Comment: it's "locust 1.4.3"

Comment: Looking more closely, it appears that you must somehow be running a pre-1.0 version of locust, otherwise it would fail already on importing HttpLocust (as that was renamed HttpUser in 1.0).

Comment: Dont ask me how though...

Comment: Try uninstalling, verifying that it is gone and then reinstalling.

Comment: Thank you.. I'll try and let you know :)

Comment: @Cyberwiz that doesn't solve the issue and my version is 2.8.6